# How to start Windows program out of Elixir?

Tags: windows, cmd, elixir

I need to start a Windows program out of Elixir Programming Language.
I tried it with :

```
System.cmd(..)
```

and

```
:os.cmd()
```

but no luck.. i've got..

```
(ErlangError) Erlang error: :enoent
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Both work perfectly, you have an induced error. Open your `cmd.exe` manually and try to execute the command exactly as you have it inside `:os.cmd/1` from there.

Answer (score 0):

Now it works..

The problem was, that i tried to call System.cmd with the "start"-Command.

When I call the program directly, it works:

```
System.cmd("C:\\Program Files\\Docker\\Docker\\Docker for Windows.exe", [])
```

The problem here is, that Elixir/ Erlang starts the program in the same process and waits until the program ends before proceeds in code.

I solved this by using a Task:

```
Task.async(fn -> System.cmd("C:\\Program Files\\Docker\\Docker\\Docker for Windows.exe", []) end)
```

I guess that's not the best way achieving this. Let me know a better solution!